# Inner workings of a self join combined with a WHERE

Tags: sql, inner-join, self-join

I have a table

```
contacts
---------
contact_id  company         contact
1000000001  Village Toys    John Smith
1000000002  Kids Place      Michelle Green
1000000003  Fun4All         Jim Jones
1000000004  Fun4All         Denise L. Stephens
1000000005  The Toy Store   Kim Howard
```

I Want to find all the contacts of the company that Jim Jones works for.
This is the correct set.

```
1000000003  Fun4All         Jim Jones
1000000004  Fun4All         Denise L. Stephens
```

I used a subquery to work this out and it works I got the correct results.
I tried then a self inner join with a where on 'Jim Jones' and I get results I cannot understand.

```
SELECT tableA.contact_id, tableA.company, tableA.contact
FROM company AS tableA
JOIN company AS tableB
ON tableA.company = tableB.company
WHERE tableB.contact = 'Jim Jones'
```

I get the correct result set

```
1000000003  Fun4All         Jim Jones
1000000004  Fun4All         Denise L. Stephens
```

But If I change the WHERE with

```
WHERE tableA.contact = 'Jim Jones'
```

I get

```
1000000003  Fun4All         Jim Jones
1000000003  Fun4All         Jim Jones
```

Why does it do that? How exactly does this works?
I spend the whole night trying to figure it out.
But it eludes me. The examples I found on Google couldn't make me undestand.

The database (In my question i changed the column names for clarification)

```
http://forta.com/books/0672336073/TeachYourselfSQL_SQLite.zip
http://forta.com/books/0672336073/TeachYourselfSQL_Oracle.zip
http://forta.com/books/0672336073/TeachYourselfSQL_MySQL.zip
http://forta.com/books/0672336073/TeachYourselfSQL_MicrosoftSQLServer.zip
http://forta.com/books/0672336073/TeachYourselfSQL_Access2007.zip
http://forta.com/books/0672336073/TeachYourselfSQL_OpenOfficeBase.zip
```

Comment: *"I don't believe that happens"* @GordonLinoff well its simply happing because [seeing is believing](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=092d25ead936177b1a399b465fab21f6) it tested more database like PostgreSQL, MySQL and MariaDB and all give the result the topicstarter says.

Comment: Run it without the where and check the values in the `contact` column and you will understand: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d5bb0e8f85eb735e8a8321283ca6460e

Comment: Try to understand this query. `SELECT *
FROM company AS tableA
JOIN company AS tableB
ON tableA.company = tableB.company`

Comment: If an answer helped, click the green tick to accept it.

Comment: I already did. Is there a second green tick?

Comment: "How exactly does this works?" It works the way inner join & where work. Please do not ask for yet another presentation, find a textbook or manual or SO one & ask about where you are stuck in it. Explain what you think should be returned  with justification. PS (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code & desired output & clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way to get the desired result.

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  company IN (SELECT company
                   FROM   TableName
                   WHERE  contact = 'Jim Jones')
```

In your query, if you're changing `WHERE tableB.contact = 'Jim Jones'` to `WHERE tableA.contact = 'Jim Jones'`, then you have to change the SELECT statement too.

```
SELECT tableA.contact_id, tableA.company, tableA.contact
FROM company AS tableA
JOIN company AS tableB
ON tableA.company = tableB.company
WHERE tableB.contact = 'Jim Jones'

SELECT tableB.contact_id, tableB.company, tableB.contact
FROM company AS tableA
JOIN company AS tableB
ON tableA.company = tableB.company
WHERE tableA.contact = 'Jim Jones'
```

You have to do this because you are filtering from this result.
(You are doing a self-join using `company` column.)

```
SELECT *
FROM company AS tableA
JOIN company AS tableB
ON tableA.company = tableB.company

+-----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
| contact_id (A)  |  company (A)   |     contact (A)     | contact_id (B) |  company (B)   |     contact (B)     |
+-----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
|      1000000001 | Village Toys   | John Smith          |     1000000001 | Village Toys   | John Smith          |
|      1000000002 | Kids Place     | Michelle Green      |     1000000002 | Kids Place     | Michelle Green      |
|      1000000003 | Fun4All        | Jim Jones           |     1000000003 | Fun4All        | Jim Jones           |
|      1000000004 | Fun4All        | Denise L. Stephens  |     1000000003 | Fun4All        | Jim Jones           |
|      1000000003 | Fun4All        | Jim Jones           |     1000000004 | Fun4All        | Denise L. Stephens  |
|      1000000004 | Fun4All        | Denise L. Stephens  |     1000000004 | Fun4All        | Denise L. Stephens  |
|      1000000005 | The Toy Store  | Kim Howard          |     1000000005 | The Toy Store  | Kim Howard          |
+-----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: OMGoodness I get it! Thank you!. The subquery way was clear, but what helped me is the last code you posted with both tables side by side.

Comment: Hmm, I have a subquestion. Why Table B, sorts contacts in this order and not the exact order like in table A?

Answer (score 2):

To get an explanation do this:

1) make the other table (self join) visible to see the result you actually get when joining without the where clause:

> select A.contactid, A.company, A.contact, B.contactid, B.company, B.contact
>   from contacts A
>   inner join contacts B
>   on A.company = B.company

[image: self joined tables]

2) now add your WHERE clause and exchange A.contact with B.contact to see what happens

Comment: Thank you! I finally grapsed it! Your answer is precise too and correct, but DxTx's seemed more clear to me!